# Conditional formatting that used to work in Google Sheets, not anymore

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

A few months back I used to use a conditional formatting to highlight duplicates in a column. The formula I used is: =COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1.
It doesn't seem to be working anymore. When I try to add this as the custom formula, I get an error message: Invalid formula. I even opened a few older sheets to check, it still works on them. Any tips?

Comment: Change the `,` to a `;`. I think your sheet might be in a different locale.

Comment: Which locale is your spreadsheet set to?

Answer (score 0):

[General Grievance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4294399/general-grievance)'s comment:

> Change the `,` to a `;`. I think your sheet might be in a different locale.